# jQuery Dialog positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI to display a dialog but I would like to reposition the window exactly under the button when it opens.

Can someone help me with that?

The code:

http://jsfiddle.net/ntenisOT/vJNRj/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and [outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) to compute the appropriate coordinates, and the [position](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-position) option to reposition the dialog widget:

```
var $opener = $("#opener");
var offset = $opener.offset();
$("#dialog").dialog("option", "position",
    [offset.left, offset.top + $opener.outerHeight()]);
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vJNRj/4/).

**EDIT:** Using the same button to close the dialog involves checking its status in your `click` handler:

```
$opener.click(function() {
    var $dialog = $("#dialog");
    var verb = $dialog.dialog("isOpen") ? "close" : "open";
    $dialog.dialog(verb);
    return false;
});
```

Updated fiddle [there](http://jsfiddle.net/vJNRj/7/).

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Is it possible to close the dialog using the same button?? Can you please give me a hint or update jfiddle please?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) 1000% thanks.. I ll probably read more about jquery soon. It seems to be AMAZING!